# Managing redis keys using wildcards in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, redis

I use cakephp 2 and redis.

How do I remove all keys from cache by the wildcards mask? 
For example I want to remove all by mask "prefix_element_group1*"

About clearGroup I know. 
But it only increments the group value to simulate deletion of all keys under a group old values will remain in storage until they expire.

At least how to get a list of keys using a mask? similar to "keys *" in redis-cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't specific to CakePHP. You can delete arbitrary keys with wildcard support using Lua scripts with [eval](http://redis.io/commands/eval). Here's a PHP example:

```
$deleteScript = 'return redis.call("DEL", unpack(redis.call("keys", ARGV[1])))';
$redis = getRedisConnection(); // whatever CakePHP provides
$redis->eval($deleteScript, 0, "keyPattern:*");
```

Obviously the exact syntax will differ based on your particular Redis library, but hopefully this should give you the right idea.